# boost programming options crashes my app

Tags: c++, boost

Why is this crashing when I use this command line: "program -p 1" instead of "program --p 1"

I compiled it with VS 2008 and used boost 1.51.

```
options_description desc("XXX");
desc.add_options()("p", value<std::string>(), "pi")
    ("s", value<std::string>(), "es");

std::cout << desc << std::endl;

variables_map vm;
store(parse_command_line(argc, argv, desc), vm);
notify(vm);
if (vm.count("p"))
    cout << "p is: " << vm["p"].as<string>() << endl;

if (vm.count("s"))
    cout << "s is: " << vm["s"].as<string>() << endl;
```

Comment: have determined where it crashed in a debugger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, it crashes with an un handled exception:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x76dbc41f in test.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::program_options::unknown_option> > at memory location 0x0018efd8..
```

It doesn't recognise your `-p` basically so reading the docs I found that it is expecting the argument to be the long argument. That is why it requires and works with the `--p`.

here is a modified source (compilable)

```
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
#include <iostream> 
#include <string> 

int main(unsigned int argc, const char** argv) 
{ 
boost::program_options::options_description desc("XXX");

desc.add_options()
    ("p-arg,p", boost::program_options::value<std::string>(), "pi")
    ("s", boost::program_options::value<std::string>(), "es");

std::cout << desc << std::endl;

boost::program_options::variables_map vm;
boost::program_options::store(
            boost::program_options::parse_command_line(argc, argv, desc), vm);

boost::program_options::notify(vm);

if (vm.count("p-arg"))
    std::cout << "p is: " << vm["p-arg"].as<std::string>() << std::endl;

if (vm.count("s"))
    std::cout << "s is: " << vm["s"].as<std::string>() << std::endl;

}
```

you'll need to put in exception handling `try-catch` to handle unrecognised program options or you may have further crashes.

Comment: Also my expectation was to have the "p" option handled by default, without crashing, in both forms ("--p" and "-p") since it is the same option (I didn't specify a different name for the long option). But I may be wrong in my expectation :)

Answer (score 3):

Boost progam options take `--` as default option start character sequence. If you want to have *'single letter'* options starting with a single `-` character supported, you'll need specifying

```
desc.add_options()("p,p", value<std::string>(), "pi")
```

I guess the program crash happens somewhere after the lines of code you're showing. You should debug (or use further `cout` statements) to determine the point of crash more exactly.